# O que são threads daemon em Java e quando utilizá-las?

Tags: java, multithreading, concorrência

Da documentação Java obenho o seguinte trecho:

> The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.

Mas ainda não está claro pra mim quando devo setar uma thread como daemon ou não. Alguém teria uma definição mais clara, de preferência com um exemplo? Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Daemon threads*** são interrompidas quando a *thread* principal, aquela que executa o método `main`, termina de executar e o programa termina.

Se uma *thread* [**não** é *daemon*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isDaemon()), o processo Java continua ativo e executando, mesmo quando atinge o final do método `main` e a *thread* principal termina.

Por padrão, as *threads* herdam a propriedade de ser *daemon* da *thread* que as criou. Como a *thread* principal **não** é *daemon*, comumente as *threads* criadas no programa também não são.

Isso torna comum programas que "não terminam", principalmente porque poucos entendem esse conceito ou esquecem de criar um mecanismo para finalizar *threads* criadas durante a execução do programa principal.